# Split strings using a pattern

Tags: regex, r, string

Initial vector is

```
"WhiteRiver"   "microProcess" "PartsUnknown" "RedSox"
```

How do I split this to

```
White"   "River"   "micro"   "Process" "Parts"   "Unknown" "Red"  "Sox"
```

The rule is to split between upper and lower case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `v1` is the vector

```
unlist(strsplit(v1, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", perl=TRUE))
#[1] "White"   "River"   "micro"   "Process" "Parts"   "Unknown" "Red"    
#[8] "Sox"
```

`(?<=[a-z])` lookbehind for lower case letters

`(?=[A-Z])`  lookahead for upper case letters

Comment: Nitpicking: `perl = T` is bad practice, use `perl = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `v1` like @akrun:

```
unlist(strsplit(sub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1,\\2", v1), ","))
#[1] "White"   "River"   "micro"   "Process" "Parts"   "Unknown" "Red"     "Sox"
```

Use `gsub` instead of `sub` if there are more than two words to split (e.g. `WhiteRiverPark`)